# How to present an Alert with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

In `SwiftUI` I discovered the `Alert` type. But I wonder how to show it with the `presentation` method.

Initializing an `Alert` is pretty easy. But how to use the binding?

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Don't know how to use the `binding` below
            presentation(binding, alert: {
                Alert(title: Text("Hello"))
            })
        }, label: {
            Text("asdf")
        })
    }
}
```

The binding is of type `Binding<Bool>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `@State` variable as the binding. Alternatively you can use a `@EnvironmentObject` variable that uses a `BindableObject`.

I think you need to call `presentation` on the root View to get it to work, adding it to a `Stack`, `Group`, etc. doesn't seem to work.

This snippet seems to do the trick. Note that `@State` variable is set to false after the alert is dismissed.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showsAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showsAlert = true
        }, label: {
            Text("asdf")
        }).presentation($showsAlert, alert: {
            Alert(title: Text("Hello"))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could use a `PresentationButton`, that does what you do in less code

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is no longer correct because `.presentation` has been deprecated in SwiftUI.

Comment: How would this be modified to handle Alerts with handlers!? Swift had the ability to have handlers.

Answer (score 33):

`.presentation()` was actually deprecated in Beta 4. Here is a version that currently works with the `.alert()` Modifier.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showsAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showsAlert.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: self.$showsAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Hello"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we use it in a Helper? As we have to call Alert many times.

Comment: I would like to know as well. I would love to have a helper: "showAlert" which expects a title and a text. And for example shows a generic alert if no parameters are provided. I tried to implement this as an extension for view struct but no chance to get it working :/.

Comment: You can make a [simple extension like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533167/5623035) @Schnodderbalken

Answer (score 15):

[**Full Code of Alert with dismiss and okay action:**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/09/swiftui-alert-example.html)

**Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isAlert = false

    var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.isAlert = true
            }) {
                Text("Click Alert")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .alert(isPresented: $isAlert) { () -> Alert in
                Alert(title: Text("iOSDevCenters"), message: Text("This Tutorial for SwiftUI Alert."), primaryButton: .default(Text("Okay"), action: {
                    print("Okay Click")
                }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")))
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Output:

[`Output`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rri5V.png)

Answer (score 10):

Here's the solution for presenting **multiple** alerts. Works on **iOS13-iOS15**:

```
struct YourView: View {
    enum AlertType: Identifiable {
        case first, second
        
        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }
    
    @State var alertType: AlertType?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show alert #1") {
                alertType = .first
            }
            
            Button("Show alert #2") {
                alertType = .second
            }
        }
        .alert(item: $alertType) { type in
            switch type {
            case .first:
                return Alert(title: Text("First alert"))
            case .second:
                return Alert(title: Text("Second alert"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @tsp's answer, to display an alert with two buttons and handle button tap action, you can do as below:

```
@State var showAlert = false

var body: some View {
  Button(action: {
    self.showAlert = true
  }) {
    Text("Show Alert")
  }
  .presentation($showAlert) {
      Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message..."),
          primaryButton: .default (Text("OK")) {
            print("OK button tapped")
          },
          secondaryButton: .cancel()
      )
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**SwiftUI present Alert**

Example with `onTapGesture`

```
struct MyRow: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello")
            Text("World")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been unable to get alerts to work from draggesture in swiftui. Anu idea how to do it in this case? Thanks!
                    .overlay(Rectangle()
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 50)
                                .onEnded { gesture in
                                    if correct gesture... {
                                        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                                            Alert()... this alert does not compile

Answer (score 3):

<sub>In addition to @thisIsTheFoxe 's answer, you can implement a simple extension:</sub>

#### Extension

```
public extension View {
    func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
               title: String,
               message: String? = nil,
               dismissButton: Alert.Button? = nil) -> some View {

        alert(isPresented: isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text(title),
                  message: {
                    if let message = message { return Text(message) }
                    else { return nil } }(),
                  dismissButton: dismissButton)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

So you can now use it easily like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showsAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            self.showsAlert.toggle()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showsAlert, title: "title", message: "Message") // <- Here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var aAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Alert").tapAction {
            self.aAlert = true
        }.presentation($aAlert, alert:{ Alert(title: Text("Alert"))})
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit? For example, explanations about interesting parts of your code snippet, or links to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

**SwiftUI**

First create basic alert :

```
Alert(title: Text("Alert title"), message: Text("Alert message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
```

Then define a bindable condition that tells when the alert will be visible or not. Toggle that condition to show/hide the alert.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```swift
public extension View {
    func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
               title: String,
               message: String? = nil,
               dismissButton: Alert.Button? = nil) -> some View {

        alert(isPresented: isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text(title),
                  message: {
                    if let message = message { return Text(message) }
                    else { return nil } }(),
                  dismissButton: dismissButton)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from ***@MojtabaHosseini***'s answer?