# How to show alertview or custom overlay in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Currently, I am wondering how to display alertview or any custom view as an overlay to display a message to the user using `SwiftUI`.

`SwiftUI` provided replacement for `UIDatepicker` with `struct DatePicker`, is there any similar `struct` present for `UIAlertController`?

If no, then how to display `View` or custom view like an alert view.

I went through couple of WWDC videos and some `SwiftUI` tutorials but didn't found any view `struct` that supports alertview behaviour.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/56448388/1187415 and this https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506785/1187415 ?

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56496896/2890168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `presentation` method for alert

```swift
var body: some View {
        Text("Placeholder").presentation(.constant(true)) { () -> Alert in
            Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: nil, dismissButton: Alert.Button.cancel())
        }
    }
```

and for actionSheet too:

```swift
Text("").presentation(ActionSheet(title: Text("Placeholder")))
```

Comment: Sorry, this no longer works in SwiftUI 3.0